# UI and Camera issue

Tags: apportable

I done with porting  to android.My game is in landscape mode. After porting to andriod, i am facing these issues, please help me.

1. I am having issue with UI. I had implemented following code( we  need  only for tablets) but images are still streached(ios target: 1024X768).Please find the attachment for difference.

   [UIScreen mainScreen].currentMode =
   [UIScreenMode emulatedMode:UIScreenIPadEmulationMode];

   [image]Sliding progress bar is also not working(you can see in attached image).Please explain whats the problem.
   If you observe in table view the right sprite is streached.Please help me in this case.
   2.I am using camera option which is not working in android(on clicking camere it is going to Galary).
2. We are using sprite sheets for images, but i am getting black screen in andriod(It is working fine in ios case:).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To avoid stretching use `UIScreenScaledAspectFitEmulationMode` or one of the Native modes. See the full list of screen modes and their descriptions in `.apportable/SDK/System/UIKit/UIScreenMode.h`

Comment: I had tested with all modes but no one is fitted exactly.Some what UIScreenMode emulatedMode is working fine.Whats the problem i am not getting.